# Designing database entity that can only have exactly one of 2 foreign key?

Tags: .net, database, hibernate, nhibernate, database-design

A process in our system is responsible for sending files according to certain rules. Depending on its filename, a file can be sent to a customer or a factory (but never both).

Each line of the rule will contain the filename filter, the customer and factory that it belongs to, and  specify other parameters such as the destination folder, whether the file needs to be encrypted, split, combined, renamed, etc.

In the process, we will know the factory and the customer that a file belongs to, and we will look at the rules for the factory and the customer and apply the rules for files that matches the filter (priority will be given to customer rules)

What is the best way to represent the relationship between the rules and the customer/factory in the database? We already have Customer and Factory table in the database, but I can't think of the best way to represent the relationship. Each line of rule will have exactly one FK (either Customer or Factory, it can't have both and it can't have none). One of the way to represent this is like:

[image]

But this doesn't capture the fact that it can only have exactly one of the two FKs. We can put a constraint that one of them needs to be valid FK and the other has to be empty, but it doesn't seem to be very clean. Besides, it will get uglier if we have other determinant of the rules (e.g. Country). Any idea how to improve this design?

I think it will also help to specify that the system is developed in .NET, and we use an object-relational mapping, namely NHibernate.

Comment: If there's some shared data between customers and factories, the obvious is to introduce a base class that both customers and factories derive from. The FK would then go to the base class

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [table inheritance](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server).

You could use something like this:

```
Rule
  int RuleId
  int TypeRule
  PK (RuleId)
  UQ (RuleId, TypeRule)

CustomerRule
  int TypeRule = 1
  int CustomerId
  FK (TypeRule, RuleId)
  FK CustomerId

FactoryRule
  int TypeRule = 2
  int FactoryId
  FK (TypeRule, RuleId)
  FK FactoryId
```

With a system like this you have either a customer rule or a factory rule, not both. Plus, it's easy to add a CountryRule tomorrow.

Comment: is this a SQL server feature? any idea how it works with NHibernate?

Answer (score 3):

Using Hibernate and its [Table-per-Subclass Mapping Strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) you can define an abstract Rule-Class, specialize it for Customers and Factories and map the class hierarchy to the relational database schema like this:

[image: Mapping]

Answer (score 1):

What about introducing a new entity instead of 2 FK's? It will have 3 fields, namely its own PK, and two FK's. Than you'll be able to introduce some custom logic for having one of those FK's empty. It will be logically clearer that you have exactly one FK for that task, and that respective entity takes care of the details.

Answer (score 1):

I know you mention the fact that you don't want to use constraints for this, however reading any of the answers and the fact that they point in the direction of table inheritance I want to tell a little bit of my personal experience.

The database is not meant to replicate object oriented principles and I am not sure about NHibernate, but Entity Framework is pretty strict in the fact that once you implement this inheritance, you will possibly hit the fact that you want to inherit to several types, which is not possible (in EF that's a fact). What I mean is that you have a rule which can be defined as both a customerrule and a factoryrule (or maybe any other type of rule the system will know in the future).

I have done both table inheritance and the implementation of constraints and the latter provided me with the most flexible model in the end, and I am still pretty happy with this solution. It is good you are thinking about the simplest approach with the least effort, but sometimes it is just a fact that a complex problem requires a less that extremely simple solution.